# selectedlistitem selected property

Tags: model-view-controller, selecteditem

I have ready list

```
 List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();  
 List<SelectListItem> list = dateParts.year;
```

and I would like to change the selected property of one Item to 'true'. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would you declare list twice?

if you already know which array of list that u want to change, maybe you can do something like this :

```
List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
list = dateParts.year;
list[1].Selected = true;
```

Comment: your welcome. if you have further questions, you can ask